# VMware Workstation 12 Player constantly freezes

Tags: freeze, vmware-workstation

I'm using VMware Workstation 12 Player with no license, for personal use, on a Windows 7 host (8 Gb RAM, 4 cores, 8 logical processors).
With a CentOS 7 guest (1 Gb RAM, 1 CPU) I'm experiencing constant freezes - every 5-15 minutes - of both the host and the guest. The freeze persists for 30 secs or so, then everything is back to normal.

How to solve this annoying problem?

Removing all unused devices (printers, soundcard etc) from the guest hardware didn't help much. CPU and RAM of the host is still mostly free.

This issue didn't arise when I was using an old version of VMware player.

EDIT: Same issue with Scientific Linux CERN 6.8 (a CentOS 6 derivative). It's clear that the problem lies in the VMware Player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by downgrading to VMware Player 8.  The Scientific Linux CERN VM works flawlessly; haven't tested yet the CentOS 7 VM but I'm pretty optimistic about it.